# TSQL 2005 Join WhiteSpace issue

Tags: t-sql, join

```
select distinct 

  zbe.BelegNr, k.FM_ID, k.FM_NR, zbe.EinkBeleg, Right(k.Fertigmeldung, 7) 

from 

  Wosit.SAP_ZBEAusw_All_Raw zbe 
    inner join 
  Wosit.Kanlog_SCM_Data2_raw k on zbe.EinkBeleg = Right(**rtrim**(k.Fertigmeldung), 7) 

where 
  k.FM_ID = 730664
```

The real strange thing:
with rtrim I get 0 records back, but when I remove the rtrim, I get 16.000 records back.

The column zbe.EinkBeleg has a Len = 0, its empty but not *null*

The column k.Fertigmeldung contains many whitespaces at the end

So it seems, that empty `string = '       '` (7 WhiteSpaces) in a join

Does that makes any sence?

Marcel

Comment: All of the data in the zbe.EinkBeleg column is an empty string?

Comment: So you're saying this works: `zbe.EinkBeleg = Right(k.Fertigmeldung, 7)`; but this doesn't: `zbe.EinkBeleg = Right(**rtrim**(k.Fertigmeldung), 7)`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an [ANSI SQL specification](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) - trailing spaces are not significant in comparison.